# Parse df output by columns

Tags: macos, bash, awk, df

I'm having difficulty extracting the **Filesystem** and **Mounted on** columns from the df ouput.

```
$df -Hl
```

Results in

```
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                          250G   226G    24G    91% 1576021 4293391258    0%   /
localhost:/BJeZ62GypQBU7sxaZg0qP6   250G   250G     0B   100%       0          0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
/dev/disk2s1                         16G   4.7G    11G    30%       0          0  100%   /Volumes/NO NAME
/dev/disk3s1                         15G   8.0G   7.5G    52%       0          0  100%   /Volumes/FLASH DRIVE
```

Adding column selection

```
df -Hl | awk '{ print $1"\t"$9 }'
```

results in

```
Filesystem  Mounted
/dev/disk1  /
localhost:/BJeZ62GypQBU7sxaZg0qP6   /Volumes/MobileBackups
/dev/disk2s1    /Volumes/NO
/dev/disk3s1    /Volumes/FLASH
```

My **Mounted on** column has spaces in the file name which is throwing off results. (ie I get "NO" instead of "NO NAME")  How do I get the columns to include the entire mount name?

Comment: Does your version of `df` support the `--output` option? df --output=source,target

Comment: I'd think parsing df is as bad as parsing ls.... can you get the mount info from /sys or /proc some how?

Comment: `diskutil list external`

Returns

`/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 NO NAME                 16.0 GB    disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk3
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 FLASH DRIVE             15.5 GB    disk3s1`

That looks harder!?

Comment: @choroba - no I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field with spaces is the last part of the line, you could just grab all the fields from 9 to the end.

```
df -Hl | awk '{ mounted=$9; 
                for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) mounted = mounted " " $i;
                print $1 "\t" mounted }'
```

This will work as long as the parts of the mount point name are just separated by single spaces -- multiple spaces and/or tabs will be compressed into a single space.

And none of the other fields can have spaces in them.